# How can I get the top 3 most frequent elements of a data frame?

Tags: r

I have this data frame in simplified version:

```
      CustomerID
1     3
2     3
3     3
4     2
5     3
6     2
7     5
8     2
9     3
10    5
11    5
12    2
13    6
14    5
```

Let's say I wanted to make a table with the top 3 customers, something like this:

```
      CustomerID     Times
1     3                5
2     2                4
3     5                3
```

What can I do?

In reality, I want to make a top 10 list of thousands of customers. I then want to put them in a chart using ggplot2 (don't need help with this, just for context).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a dplyr approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  count(id, name = "Times", sort = TRUE) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not quite necessary but if you create a frequency table you can better sort them based on their occurrence:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

df %>%
  tabyl(CustomerID) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  slice_head(n = 3) %>%
  select(-percent)

CustomerID n
           3 5
           2 4
           5 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
out <- stack(table(df$CustomerID))
tail(out[order(out$values),], 3)[2:1]
  ind values
1   2      4
3   5      4
2   3      5
```